# Как проапгрейтить ноутбук Fujitsu-Siemens LIFEBOOK S7020?

Tags: windows, ноутбук

Здравствуйте!

Давно-давно (в 2006 году), был куплен по тем временам хороший ноутбук [Fujitsu-Siemens LIFEBOOK S7020](http://market.yandex.ru/model-spec.xml?modelid=763910&hid=91013), его характеристики полностью соответствую описанию как на яндекс.маркете. Я нашёл его обзор [тут](http://www.ferra.ru/ru/notebooks/s26243/page-1/), думаю, это поможет вам ответить на мой вопрос. У меня от этого ноутбука есть все то же самое, что и в статье с его обзором.В наличие у меня всё, что и в стетье + документанция.

Ситуация такая:
Он использовался только для проверки почты, рааботы с MS office 2003 и всё.Его использовали в период с 2006 по 2008, затем он 2 года пролежал на полке (аккамулятор вообще сдох уже к этому моменту), затем он понадобился и с 2010 года он опять стал активно использоваться.
Но проблема:
Он очень сильно тупит на родной Windows XP. Если систему сносить и устанавливать заново, то он быстро работает только 1 месяц. Затем он опять страшно тупит.Я решил установить Windows 7, и это реально помогло, он стал работать медленно, но без глюков и тормозов. Но Windows 7 нужно переустанавливать каждые 6 месяцев.

**Как можно проапрейдить ноутбук, что б он стал быстрее?**

***PS**: Я сам собрал свой компьютер, поэтому что-то поменять для меня - не проблема. Просто я не имел дело с ноутбуками, поэтому прошу совета у Вас.*

Comment: Ремонт и обслуживание электроники не входит в допустимую тематику сайта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Нарастить объем оперативной памяти до 1ГБ, лучше до 2ГБ (2 плашки по 1ГБ).
2. Поменять винчестер на более емкий и быстрый. Учесть, что жесткие диски для этой модели скорее всего будут под интерфейс PATA. Можно найти и новые такие, но они будут стоить дороже, чем аналогичный б/у ноутбук.
3. Обновить процессор на более старшую модель. Например, PM-2.1. Плюсы - будет работать быстрее. Процентов на 10-20. Минусы - ноутбук будет работать существенно меньше от АКБ и будет греться сильнее. А в ноутбуках, как известно, система охлаждения сделана без запаса.

Обратить особое внимание на состояние ноутбука. Очень беспокоит состояние системы охлаждения. Она зачастую бывает забита пылью, что приводит к тормозам и глюкам. Вплоть до зависаний и самопроизвольных выключений. Вообще существует рекомендация чистить ноутбук не реже раза в полгод. При использовании в грязных условиях (цех или, например, в кровати) - чаще.

Очень рекомендую еще просканировать жесткий диск на наличие сбойных секторов. Делается это утилитой Victoria for Windows. Заодно и SMART посмотрите.

Comment: Спасибо. Ноутбук чищу каждый месяц пылесосом и влажной тряпкой. Там кулер шумит, горячий воздух выгоняет, но он сильно горячий всегда.

Comment: Кстати, вместо переустановки W7 каждые полгода, можно сэкономить время и собрать образ со всеми программами. А потом просто его заливать. На текущий момент времени лучшее решение для этой задачи - Acronis TrueImage

Comment: По поводу замены процессора - конкретно у этого ноутбука процессор не заменяемый, поэтому человек, который только "сам собрал свой компьютер", вряд ли справится с этим.

Comment: Ну, с тем, что процессор впаян - как повезет. Заранее не узнаешь, пока не залезешь. В большинстве ноутбуков процессор стоит в разъеме и его можно заменить.

Comment: Я разобарал ноутбук, процессор не припаян. Можно поменять.